# Убрать тэг из результата, если в нем нет значений

Tags: php, xml

Есть код:

```
<block-2>

<?php if ($this->checkPosition('cell-1')) : ?>
<cell-1><?php echo $yml->replaceSpecial($this->renderPosition('cell-1')); ?></cell-1>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($this->checkPosition('cell-2')) : ?>
<cell-2><?php echo $yml->replaceSpecial($this->renderPosition('cell-2')); ?></cell-2>
<?php endif; ?>

</block-2>
```

Как видно из примера, позиции cell-1 и cell-2 обрамляются тэгами `<block-2></block-2>`, и в конечном xml файле будет содержаться строчка:

```
<block-2>
<cell-1>Значение-1</cell-1>
<cell-2>Значение-2</cell-2>
</block-2>
```

Однако, если в этих позициях ничего не стоит, в xml появляется вот такая конструкция:

```
<block-2></block-2>
```

Как правильно оформить код, чтобы при отсутствии значений конструкция `<block-2></block-2>` не выводилась? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед всей этой конструкцией можно поставить условие

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('cell-1') || $this->checkPosition('cell-2')) : ?>
```

а после - завершение

```
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Работает, именно то, что нужно!